# Checkout Step Progess Doesn't Return Complete Status

Tags: checkout, billing

I'm fairly new in the Magento environment. I've downloadet a free theme and it's all working great.
But when i want to checkout when logged in, the progress steps wont show billing address or shipping method.

I've copied almost all of the lines from the "base" theme to my custom theme.
But no luck.

How could that be?

It is as if onepage doesn't return "complete" when i click next step.

> Line 27 in "checkout/onepage/progress/billing.phtml"
>
> `if ($this->getCheckout()->getStepData('billing', 'complete')):`

*I havn't changed anything en "opcheckout.js".*

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Please check Magento and Apache logs for errors. Also check the console in your browser for any javascript errors

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't get any errors anywhere what so ever. :/

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the error...
Magento 1.9 uses folder mapping:

- app/design/default/MY_THEME/template/checkout/onepage.phtml
- app/design/default/MY_THEME/template/checkout/progress.phtml
- app/design/default/MY_THEME/template/checkout/progress/billing.phtml
- app/design/default/MY_THEME/template/checkout/progress/payment.phtml
- app/design/default/MY_THEME/template/checkout/progress/shipping.phtml
- app/design/default/MY_THEME/template/checkout/progress/shipping_method.phtml

When older versions used:

- app/design/default/MY_THEME/template/checkout/progress.phtml

You can always check base theme for reference.

Thanks